# UnsupportedOperationException al cambiar el valor de la variable que va estar en el return del método

Tags: java, java-ee, jdbc

```
public boolean tieneBono(String correo,Properties sql) throws SQLException
{       
        boolean bonoExist=false;
        con.DBConnection();
        connection = con.getJdbcConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql.getProperty("tieneBono"));
        ps.setString(1, correo);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      
        while(rs.next())
        {
            int numero=rs.getInt("n_sesiones");
            if(numero>0) {
                bonoExist=true;
            }
            
        }
        con.desconectar();
        ps.close();
    

    return bonoExist;
}
```

Cuando cambio el valor de bonoExist a true me da UnsupportedOperationException. Se supone que se lanza cuando intentas hacer algo que no está permitido en ese objeto, pero creo que este no es el caso. Si quito la linea de bonoExist=true; ya no salta ninguna excepción. Lo he intentado hacerlos con otros tipos como String o Int, pero al cambiar el valor del valor del return me salta la excepción. Y si devuelvo directamente el valor pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Hola Ignacio, bienvenido, el problema está en la linea **int numero = rs.getInt( "n_sesiones" );**, obviamente, **"n_sesiones"** no es un entero válido...

Comment: No creo que el problema sea la línea: `bonoExist=true;`. Probando por ejemplo un `while` basado en incrementos, el error no ocurre. Como dice @MarcePuente, quizá la columna `n_sesiones` no es `integer` en tu tabla. De todos modos, aunque funcione, es un pésimo código. Si tu tabla tiene un millón de registros, ¿vas a empezar a recorrer ese millón de registros hasta ver si el bono existe, en el registro `1` o en el registro `999999`? Haz un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTabla WHERE laCondicion` y verifica que esa consulta trae más de una fila, así ya sabrás si el bono existe o no.

Comment: @A.Cedano Haciendo esa consulta SQL ya funciona. Gracias, todavía me queda mucho por aprender.